# magento sends invoices and shipment notification only to me, not to the costomer

Tags: email, magento

I have a multi-store, 1 website with 2 stores that have each 2 store-views (languages).

On new customer registration and order confirmations e-mails are sent correctly (to me and to the customer). 
However, when I create the invoice and prepare the shipment from the backend, the mail is only sent to me, but not to the customer.

In the system->config->sales->sales emails 
I have for every store view a different e-mail template configured. Since I receive all mails without problem (and my customers some mails), I assume the templates and the e-mail configuration are set correctly.

I already tried to add me in copy as 'BCC' and as 'separate email' without success.

Does anyone know what I am missing or what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

ps I don't know if it could make a difference, but I am having an external email provider and don't use 'localhost' to send emails. 
pps I am using Magento 1.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cron job is setup for Magento. Depending on your email provider, they may need one as well. Here is more info on setting the main cron job: http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob